# Laravel multi-relation joins with sum and count sorting and where

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm attempting to create a small system to manage my company exporting department, I'm trying to join 3 tables listed below:

```
mysql> select id,code,name,country from customers limit 10;
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| id | code  | name                                 | country                     |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | t1584 | Swift Group                          | Tuvalu                      |
|  2 | k5583 | Brown, Hauck and Wolff               | Bhutan                      |
|  3 | o8481 | Mueller-Barrows                      | Haiti                       |
|  4 | e176  | Waters-Anderson                      | Mozambique                  |
|  5 | e3276 | Stehr, Lockman and Jacobs            | Congo                       |
|  6 | w69   | Howell PLC                           | French Southern Territories |
|  7 | o881  | Skiles-Fritsch                       | France                      |
|  8 | x2925 | Boyle-Haag                           | Uganda                      |
|  9 | k6534 | Macejkovic, Satterfield and Tremblay | South Africa                |
| 10 | y773  | Morissette Inc                       | United Kingdom              |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,code,customer_id from orders limit 30;
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | code     | customer_id |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 | ORD67703 |           1 |
|  2 | ORD84022 |           1 |
|  6 | ORD29040 |           2 |
|  7 | ORD70298 |           2 |
|  9 | ORD40493 |           3 |
| 10 | ORD89299 |           3 |
| 11 | ORD35719 |           3 |
| 12 | ORD17115 |           4 |
| 18 | ORD62357 |           5 |
| 21 | ORD70979 |           5 |
| 22 | ORD20614 |           6 |
| 23 | ORD90549 |           6 |
| 24 | ORD95016 |           6 |
| 25 | ORD11464 |           6 |
| 26 | ORD39202 |           6 |
| 27 | ORD42648 |           6 |
| 28 | ORD72554 |           7 |
| 29 | ORD74224 |           8 |
| 30 | ORD59620 |           9 |
+----+----------+-------------+
30 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,order_id,customer_id,item_id,quantity from order_items limit 300;
+-----+----------+-------------+---------+----------+
| id  | order_id | customer_id | item_id | quantity |
+-----+----------+-------------+---------+----------+
|   1 |        1 |           1 |       8 |   143000 |
|   2 |        1 |           1 |      27 |   143000 |
|   3 |        1 |           1 |      13 |    85800 |
...........
...........
+-----+----------+-------------+---------+----------+
300 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm trying to make html table with form to filtering and sorting the below data

1. company code
2. company name
3. company country
4. company orders = count of
5. company orders quantities = sum of company orders items

My Code
Get Data

```
$items = new Customer();
$items->withCount('orders');
$items->with('ordersItems');
```

Filtering Not working with all columns

```
if (Input::has('code')) {
   $items->where('code', '=', Input::get('code'));
}
```

Ordering / sorting 
working with customers table columns and orders count only

```
$items->orderBy($request->order->column', $request->order->dir);
```

Limits - working well

```
$items->limit($request->length)->offset($request->start);
$items->groupBy('customers.id');
$items->get();
```

Output data

```
$item->code,
$item->name,
$item->country,
$item->orders_count,
$item->ordersItems()->sum('quantity'),
```

Update :

```
    $orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->select('orders.customer_id', DB::raw('COUNT(orders.customer_id) as orders_count'))
        ->groupBy('orders.customer_id');

    $quantity = DB::table('order_items')
        ->select('customer_id', DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as quantities'))
        ->groupBy('customer_id');

    $items = DB::table('customers')
        ->select(['customers.*',
            DB::raw('COALESCE(orders_count, 0) AS orders_count'),
            DB::raw('COALESCE(quantities, 0) AS quantities')])
        ->leftJoinSub($orders, 'orders', function ($join) {
            $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id');
        })->leftJoinSub($quantity, 'order_items', function ($join) {
            $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'order_items.customer_id');
        });
```

Comment: Use joins, not eager loading, for a two-dimensional representation of data.  If you look at the query log, you'll see that eager loading does not use a join.

Comment: Thanks, dear Devon, I'll try to use joins and submit the result, if you have examples can helping, I'll be thankful

Comment: @Davon still have the same problems with laravel